# How to add functions with a loop to <script> tag with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a function for every item of a list that I have in JavaScript since I don't know the total number of elements, it needs to be dynamic.
To do this without copy pasting code unlimited times, I decided to add the functions to my html script tag by adding the function to the  tag's innerHTML.
Here is my Javascript code:

```
function myfun(){
    var bro= document.getElementById('helo');
    var x=["admin","RKP",   "VK","TS","MODBK"];
    var scr=document.getElementById('addscr');
    for(i=1;i<x.length;i++){
    bro.innerHTML +="<div class=\"column\"><h2 class=\"white-text title\">asdf</h2><div class=\"col-lg-2\"> <p class=\"t\">Rank</p> <div class=\"input-group\"> <p class=\"bruh\" id=\"price\">1</p></div> </div> <div class=\"col-lg-2\"> <p class=\"t\">Attack</p> <div class=\"input-group\"> <p class=\"bruh\" id=\"attack\">0</p> </div> </div><div class=\"col-lg-2\"><p class=\"t\">Defence</p> <div class=\"input-group\"> <p class=\"bruh\" id=\"defense\">0</p> </div> </div> <button class=\"butt\" style=\"width:150px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:100px\" onclick=\"nk"+i+"()\" >Attack</button></div>";
    scr.innerHTML+="function nk"+i+"(){location.href=\"#pop"+i+"\";}";
}}
```

What this should've done is add a few functions to the script tag id="addsrc" but I get the following error in the console:

**nk1 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick**

..nk2 for the second function and so on...

What the function nk is supposed to do is it will open a modal (passed as a html # div).

Please suggest and easier way to create similar functions(with different numbers)quickly{given that I don't have the number of items in the list} or help me fix this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You 're not defining `scr`. Try `var scr = document.getElementById('addscr').innerHTML;`

Comment: @MattCroak After defining scr, I am getting this error:                                                     Uncaught ReferenceError: nk1 is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Makes no sense to even generate a function to do that. Just have a generic function and pass it the string.

Comment: @epascarello I don't know much about javascript and couldn't think of it that way. Thank you for helping.

Comment: On a sidenote, making new DOM elements with strings like that irks me the wrong way... Consider putting them into a template element (or just a `div` with `display: none;`) and copying them with `node.cloneNode(true)`. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags are only executed once, changing its text isn't going to run it again. Because of this the code you are putting into the script tag is not being run and your functions are not actually being created.

Instead of trying to make numerous functions just make a single function that you can pass the number to:

```
function nk(num){
  location.href="#pop"+num;
}
//notice the placement of "i" is changed to make 
//onclick="nk(1)" and so on
bro.innerHTML += "... onclick=\"nk("+i+")\" > ..."
```